# Python3 Django ZipFile HttpResponse UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django

I created a zip file like so:

```
        zipped_file = zipfile.ZipFile("csvOutput{}.zip".format(timestamp), 'w')
        zipped_file.write(sms_file_path)
        zipped_file.write(mail_maga_file_path)
        zipped_file.close()
```

And want to send it, which I am currently using this code:

```
        response_file = open('csvOutput{}.zip'.format(timestamp))
        response = HttpResponse(response_file, content_type="application/force-download")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=csvOutput{}.zip"'.format(timestamp)
        return response
        raise Http404
```

But maybe something I am using is out of date? Python keeps crashing with a byte it can't decode in unicode:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

Says `line 100` is throwing the error, which would be the line with `HttpResponse()`

**Edit:** I've changed the content_type to `application/zip` and am getting a new error (that seems better?):

```
caution:  zipfile comment truncated
error [output.zip]:  missing 3232109644 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [output.zip]:  attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue is with your time stamp string.

```
response_file = open('csvOutput{}.zip'.format(str(timestamp).encode('utf-8').strip()))
```

or

```
response_file = open('csvOutput{}.zip'.format(str(timestamp).encode('ISO-8859-1').strip()))
```

Comment: Even if I remove the timestamp stuff entirely, the code will not compile

Comment: Yes, if I open with 'r', Django throws: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 14: invalid start byte

Comment: if I open with 'rb', I get a file back in the frontend with unreadable characters. I can see all of the text in the response, and it starts with a filepath with unparseable characters like this: PKEY/L���w�7�7L��Users/local_dev/machine/etc...

Comment: solution to  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 14: invalid start byte'  is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the issue, by opening the file with 'rb' as in:

`response_file = open('csvOutput{}.zip'.format(timestamp), 'rb')`